# Are zero knowledge proofs alternative private key encryption?

Tags: encryption, hash, public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

Are they the alternative to private keys. If I understand correctly, because of the increasing computational power in today's world, zero knowledge proofs are more safe than private keys ?

Are these two things connected in the way I understood it, or is my understanding a bit off?

Comment: That's like asking if a washing machine is better than a frying pan.

Comment: Asking if zero knowledge proofs are an alternative to private key _signature_ instead would be an oranges to mandarins comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean for "more safe". A probable link between these notions exists when we consider a context/application: suppose we need a secure identification scheme; the adversary is listening to the channel between the identifier and the identity-server. By considering this context, we can say that an identification scheme based on a zero-knowledge proof withstands adversary attacks: eavesdrop, man-in-the-middle, replay, etc.

In this given context, an identification scheme based on private keys will fail: a secure channel is always a prerequisite to exchange private keys. Even if the private key is unconditionally unbreakable for any computational power: the adversary can tap it if no private channel exists.

Comment: doesn't zero-knowledge-proof identification schemes require some initial secure setup, too?

Comment: @kelalaka, you're correct, both require. I was trying to answer the point of the question: "because of the increasing computational power". I don't think what a ZKP based id scheme gives us is resistance to a powerful adversary, if we could make a comparison with a private key based scheme.

Comment: So, as Maeher said apples and oranges. Your base of argument fails!

Comment: @kelalaka, I agree with you about my answer being a correct, rigorous, *argument*. My thought was to give a counterexample: they are completely different things, so I  showed a scenario where computer power doesn't matter.